# How to replace the indicated values ​of a set with values ​drawn from the list

Tags: java, collections, stream

I have a complex `obj` object that contains a `CountryUnit` object that holds a collection of `countries`.
`countries` has the following `countryValue` values:

```
countries == {
                Country1 (countryValue == "A")
                Country2 (countryValue == "B")
             }
```

In this case, I need to do a transformation so that the resulting set `countries` contains the values for `countryValue` which will be replaced with the randomly selected values from `allowedCountryList`. For example:

```
countries == {
                Country1 (countryValue == "N")
                Country2 (countryValue == "S")
             }
```

Then I need to return the `obj` object already with the new values for `countryValue`. What's the easiest way to do it? I have a piece of code but it doesn't work as it should.

```
SomeObject obj; // complex object that contains multiple levels, obj contains CountryUnit object


public class CountryUnit {

      private Set<Country> countries = new HashSet<>();

      // getters, setters
}

public class Country {

        private String countryValue;

        // getters, setters
}
```

My code:

```
List<String> CountryChecker = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
List<String> allowedCountryList = Arrays.asList("L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "R", "S");

            obj.getSomeSet().stream()
                    .map(CountryUnit::getCountries)
                    .flatMap(Set::stream)
                    .filter((x) -> CountryChecker.contains(x.getCountryValue()))
                    .map(y -> {
                        Random r = new Random();
                        int rCountry = r.nextInt(allowedCountryList.size());
                        y.setCountryValue(allowedCountryList.get(rCountry));
                        return y;
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Since you are already updating existing `Country` object, use a `forEach` rather than a `map` operator on the stream.

```
obj.getSomeSet().stream()
            .map(CountryUnit::getCountries)
            .flatMap(Set::stream)
            .filter((x) -> CountryChecker.contains(x.getCountryValue()))
            .forEach(y -> {
                Random r = new Random();
                int rCountry = r.nextInt(allowedCountryList.size());
                y.setCountryValue(allowedCountryList.get(rCountry));
            });
```

And you can combine the map and the flatMap calls as:

```
obj.getSomeSet().stream()
            .flatMap(countryUnit -> countryUnit.getCountries().stream())
            .filter(country -> CountryChecker.contains(country.getCountryValue()))
            .forEach(country -> {
                Random r = new Random();
                int rCountry = r.nextInt(allowedCountryList.size());
                country.setCountryValue(allowedCountryList.get(rCountry));
            });
```

If you follow Java's naming convention, you should rename variable names to start with a lower-case (`countryChecker` or `countriesToUpdate`). It would be better if it is a `Set` because we call `contains` on it. With a set, that will be a constant time operation rather than a linear search.

Comment: Why does changing `map` to `forEach` work?

Comment: `map` is an intermediate operation whereas `forEach` is a terminal operation. The stream pipeline line will not be invoked till you add a terminal operation to it. References: [package summary of stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and [Java streams quick summary](https://javadevcentral.com/java-8-streams-are-not-completely-lazy#A_very_quick_tour_of_Java_8_streams)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks @user7